# Databricks/pyspark - insert into table with identity

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I have a problem with inserting data from a Data Frame into a Delta Table with the Identity column using Pyspark. It either fails with the schema mismatch error if I won't include the column in the Data Frame, or shouts that I cannot insert into the "generated always as identity" column.
Usually, in SQL, I would not mention the column in the columns list while inserting data. How to deal with it in Pyspark?

The made-up exemplary code would look like this:

- SQL:

```
create table sample.table (
id bigint generated always as identity (start with 1 increment by 1),
name string,
address string
)
using delta
```

- Pyspark:

```
df = df.select("name", "address")
df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("sample.table")
```

This is going to fail because of the schema mismatch. It will fail as well if do it like *df = df.select(lit(None).alias("id"), "name", "address")*.

Errors I'm getting:

- if I use *lit(None).alias("id")*:

> Providing values for GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY column
> pk_part_current is not supported.

- if I exclude the Identity column:

> **AnalysisException:** A schema mismatch detected when writing to the Delta table (Table ID: b83f1234-a178-486f-be53-2478cb4a1234). To
> enable schema migration using DataFrameWriter or DataStreamWriter,
> please set: '.option("mergeSchema", "true")'. For other operations,
> set the session configuration
> spark.databricks.delta.schema.autoMerge.enabled to "true". See the
> documentation specific to the operation for details.
>
> Table schema:
> root
> -- id: long (nullable = false)
> -- name: string (nullable = true)
> -- address: string (nullable = true)
>
> Data schema:
> root
> -- name: string (nullable = true)
> -- address string (nullable = true)
>
> To overwrite your schema or change partitioning, please set:
> '.option("overwriteSchema", "true")'.
>
> Note that the schema can't be overwritten when using 'replaceWhere'.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Please post the error you are getting. Also, you need to specify .mode("overwrite") if the table already exists.

Comment: @ChenHirsh Thanks for your reply. I've added errors to the post and .mode("overwrite"). I was using the mode originally, just forgot to add it here.

Comment: Maybe it's Databricks version related? I've tried with version 13.3 and a similar code to yours and the data is written with no error message.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the *option("mergeSchema", "true")* and it kind of helped bypassing the issue. It ought to be used prudently as it can mess the target table schema because of a simple typo, though. Combining it with the lack of dropping columns functionality (available in Public Preview currently) it can get you in troubles.